# How can I find work in a new sub-field that I have invented for my profession?

Tags: job-search, career-development, career-switch

I know that I am not supposed to be industry or profession specific, so just take the following as an example of this sort of situation.

An Example:
I call my new sub-field 'Information Programming'. I have figured out how to work with information in a computer program as well as data. From my experience in the programming profession, I can tell that 5-20% of every program would be easier to build, cheaper, easier to maintain, more reliable, and easier for users to work with using information oriented programming rather than conventional data oriented programming. It is clear to me that it will make employers money, and I can point to a track record of cost savings, as well as a long list of new opportunities that this new sub-field makes economically feasible.

Certainly other sub-fields of other professions have been invented before so this is not just a programming industry question.

Note, I have autism, so selling, consulting or starting a business are not realistic options. On the other hand, having God and having autism both gave me the cognitive ability to invent a whole new sub-field.

Comment: Are you currently employed in the profession of the sub-field that you have created?

Comment: Yes I am, I have been in the programming profession for 35 years. It took a couple decades to figure out how to do something really new.

Comment: Have you reached out to your current company to do work in this sub-field?

Comment: My current company is tiny (10 people) and has little scope for the sub-field. I have done a little bit here and I have grown in the new sub-field here, and have outgrown what I can do with it in this company. Yours is a good suggestion however for other people with the same problem.

Comment: I have autism and the nature of my autism prevents starting a company, but that is an excellent suggestion for someone else with the same dilemma who does not have autism.

Comment: You have an idea you want to sell and starting a business and/or consultancy is what will give you the best chance of working on that and making money. Since you say all of those things are not realistic for you... have you considered trying to find a partner who *can* do those things? Although you'll also have to sell your idea to them, at least. But you may be surprised at what those with autism have accomplished / learnt to do.

Comment: I am intrigued by the concept. Have you tried reaching out to educational institutes to see if they would be interested in this field for research purposes?

Comment: what do you want to happen? do you want to change jobs? do you want to work on a project within your invented sub-field? i think the question is downvoted because you didn't specify desirable outcome. Also: what is your employment history?

Comment: @jonrgrover speaking as someone with autism who has started his own company I'd say that you might be doing yourself a disservice.

Answer (score 8):

It's not really clear (to me at least) what you mean by a "new sub-field" but I suppose, per your question, that's not the point. You really have two choices:

- **Find a way to fit your new concept into what employers are already asking for.** In other words, don't call it something new - just find positions that employers are trying to fill in order to solve problems you're good at solving. Focus on the language, terms, and titles they use for these positions and describe your concepts and ideas in those terms. Ultimately, many employers care about *how* problems are solved and will want to hire people with conventional skill sets for given positions, but other employers are really just concerned with *solving problems* and are supportive of employees with creative approaches. Of course, if your intent is to explicitly look for a job in the field you're inventing, this might not be a legitimate answer to your question.
- **Become a salesperson for your idea.** If you've come up with a new position, and it's truly *new* - well, then, by definition, no one is going to be asking for it, at least not by name. If you want people to want your new idea, they first need to understand it. *Getting people to understand why they want something is called sales.* This could take many forms - but you've basically already listed many of them in your question and said you're not interested. There are some less-obvious "sales" approaches you haven't explicitly discredited, though - if your concept can be distilled into a new tool, process, framework, or development environment which can be developed and released with an open license, and it's truly as powerful as you're describing, it's possible for it to sell itself and get traction to the point where you become a desirable employee. Of course, that's not an approach you can take to the bank like a paycheck, and it may not really fit what you're asking for in terms of "finding work."

Ultimately, considering the restrictions you're placing on yourself in terms of sales, it's somewhat impossible to find work in a field that only exists to you - before anyone will be willing to pay for it, you have to *sell* it to them in some manner.

Comment: Commenting to clarify - I did not address options based on staying employed by your current employer, since by "finding work" I assumed you're not happy there and/or have already reached internal limitations which are causing you to look elsewhere.

Comment: I have been working the 'framework' approach for a while now. It is available at https://github.com/jonrgroverlib/InfoLib. I am also working on a tool. Though I have a hunch that the first approach you mention is more likely to work in the short term, especially with an employer with a real problem that is willing to accept a creative solution.

Comment: @jonrgrover since you posted your GitHub, you probably should add some small example programs written in your framework. Starting maybe with "fizzBuzz" and going up to something more relevant